# MathJax rendering in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mathjax, mathtype

I am trying to use Mathjax code generated by MathType in word. For this, I round a script added it to the header:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"> 
</script>
```

It works for making equations, however, things like color and strikethrough do not appear properly. The color works only on the initial letter, and the strikethrough just shows up as "\cancel"

I found another script that seems to solve the problem, but in this case, the Mathjax outcome is like an image and cannot be selected or searched which is not ideal for the website. Here is the script:

```html
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
```

Can you suggest a new script or a modification to these to solve the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X69JU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I also tried mathjax recently on one website and simple mathjax plugin was pretty cool and user friendly to use.
So, if you want you can use that.
here is the plugin link---
https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-mathjax/
This wordpress plugin is yet another simple plugin to load the MathJax scripts at the bottom of all of your pages. It uses a very all-inclusive mathjax configuration by default, with $’s and $$’s the default delimeters for in-line and displayed equations.

Comment: Yes, that plugin works for rendering the formulas but they are still like images and cannot be highlighted or searched.

Comment: oh ho. I am checking too. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

To use MathJax on WordPress, write the following code in header.php.
(I put the code just before  .)
That’s it!!

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({ tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'], ["\(","\)"]] } });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML">
</script>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" CONTENT="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

for details you can visit here ---
https://yutsumura.com/mathjax-in-wordpress/

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work - no rendering at all.

Comment: Then I am so sorry bro.

Comment: all pleasure is mine. But still I wish I could help ...